# R: converting table to list of vectors

Tags: r, list, dataframe, reshape

I've got an R data.frame TAB with the following content:

```
A A
A B
A C
B A
B D
```

What I would like to get is a list of vectors/lists:

```
A -> A, B, C
B -> A, D
```

I can do this with a for loop that looks something like this:

```
for (i in 1:2){
    V[[i]]<-TAB[which(is.element(TAB[,1],UA[i])),2]
}
```

Is there a more convenient way of doing this that avoids the for loop?

Comment: `split(dd$y, dd$x)` where `dd` is your data.frame and x and y are the first and second columns, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! Combining with `lapply(mysplit, as.character)` does what I want.

Comment: I don't mind if you write that down and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in that case, the snippet to solve the problem is:

```
mysplit = split(dd$y, dd$x)
myresult = lapply(mysplit, as.character)
```